# How to get the custom attributes in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

How to list the current deployments running in Kubernetes with custom columns displayed as mentioned below:

**DEPLOYMENT CONTAINER_IMAGE READY_REPLICAS NAMESPACE**

The data should be sorted by the increasing order of the deployment name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look a the `-o custom-columns` feature. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns shows the basics. The hard one would be container_image, since a pod can contain more than one, but assuming you just want the first, something like `.spec.template.containers[0].image`? Give a shot and see how it goes.

Comment: thank you for sharing the link. Yes, hardest part was something which i struggled a lot. in end able to work out with the query as kubectl get deployments -o custom-columns=DEPLOYMENT:.metadata.name,CONTAINER_IMAGE:..image,READY_REPLICAS:..replicas,NAMESPACE:..namespace

Answer (score 0):

Command to get the custom columns as per the question:

`Kubectl get deployments -o custom-columns=DEPLOYMENT:.metadata.name,CONTAINER_IMAGE:..image,READY_REPLICAS:..replicas,NAMESPACE:..namespace`